# the uniform convergence of the sequence of functions

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functional-analysis, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

Let $f_1:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a Riemann integrable function. Define the sequence of functions $f_n:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by

$f_{n+1}(x)=\int_a^x f_n(t)dt,$

for each $n\ge 1$ and each $x\in [a,b]$. Prove that the sequence of functions

$g_n(x)=\sum\limits_{k=1}^n f_k(x)$

converges uniformly on [a,b].

I try to use Ascoli Theorem to prove this problem by considering 
$|g_n(x)-gn(y)|\le\sum\limits_{k=1}^n |f_k(x)-f_k(y)|$. However, $|f_k(x)-f_k(y)|\le M |b-a|^{k-2} |x-y|, $ where $M>0$ is a constant achieving by the condition that $f_1$ is an integrable function. However, this estimation depends on $k$, so I cannot apply Ascoli-Azela Theorem.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Should the integral be from $a$ to $x$, instead of $0$ to $x$ ?

Comment: @JacksonHsu: Thank you for your correction. I just corrected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @RRL comment, I rewrite the solution as follows.

Using the following theorem to prove

*"Suppose $\{f_n\}$ is a sequence of functions defined on E, and suppose $|f_n(x)|\le M_n$ ($x\in E$, $n=1,\ 2,\ 3,\ldots$). Then $\sum f_n$ converges uniformly on $E$ if $\sum M_n$ converges."*

Since $f_1$ is a Riemann integrable function, there is a constant $M>0$ such that $|f_1(x)|\le M$ for all $x\in [a,b]$. From the assumption  $f_{n+1}(x)=\int_a^x f_n(t)dt,$ we easily get the following inequalities:
$$f_2(x)\le M(b-a),$$
$$f_3(x)\le \frac{1}{2!}M(b-a)^2,$$
$$\ldots$$
$$f_{n+1}(x)\le \frac{1}{n!}M(b-a)^n,$$

We have $M+M(b-a)+\frac{1}{2!}M(b-a)^2+ \ldots +M \frac{1}{n!}(b-a)^n+ \ldots = Me^{b-a}$. Applying the above theorem we have $g_n=\sum\limits_{k=1}^n f_k(x)$ converges uniformly on $[a,b]$.

Answer (score 5):

Hint: 
$$|f_1(x)| \leqslant M, \\|f_2(x)| \leqslant M(x-a), \\ |f_3(x)| \leqslant \frac{1}{2!}M(x-a)^2, \\ \ldots$$

Comment: Actually you want $M, M(x-a),M(x-a)^2/2!, ...$

Comment: Yes. OP changed lower limit since yesterday